# Passsing text value to next jsp page

Tags: jsp

Friends,

I want to pass variable value to next jsp page while successful execution of code.
please tell me how can I do this.

My code is:

```
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:swap");

    int cnt=0;
    pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select No from labSetting");
    rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        cnt++;
    }
    rs.close();
    pstmt.close();
    con.close();
    cnt++;
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:swap");
    pstmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into labSetting  values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
     pstmt.setInt(1,cnt);
     pstmt.setString(2,lName);
     pstmt.setString(3,sysId);
     pstmt.setString(4,loc);
     pstmt.setInt(5,1);
     pstmt.setInt(6,1);
     pstmt.executeUpdate();
     pstmt.close();
     con.close();   
/************************************************

 in this section i want to pass value of lName to the my home.jsp page

***********************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpSession`. For more info look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

One piece of advice, you don't usually put your DB access codes or complex logics in a JSP page. You do these sort of stuffs at backend, and use JSP just a view. e.g. do your stuff in a backend java classs (e.g. servlet) and pass on the results in JSP page via JSTL or HttpSession.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class with the methods for your code.
2. Crete a servlet and override `doGet` or `doPost` Method.
3. Inside the doGet or doPost method, use the HttpServletResponse object to set the attribute
   using the `setAttribute` method.

You can pass any object inside setAttribute. Use the name in the set attribute to retrieve the object back in the jsp page.